# Java eclipse Path file executable

Tags: java, path, move, transfer

I am trying to make an exe that will move a file from one folder to another automatically.I am having a hard time trying to write the code the grabs the file from my desired location. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
public class Transfer {
     Path source = C:\Users\Name\Google Drive;
             Path newdir = C:\Users\Name\Desktop;
             Files.move(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Also 1) place your code in `main` method 2) `import` needed classes 3) take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html#create) for info about how to create Path objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try mkyong.com solution on file manipulation:http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/

Comment: yes, this would work. The only problem is pasting the file to the destination folder.

Comment: *What* is the problem? Access permission issues?

Comment: I got it to work after a little debugging on the file itself. Well Done @Tabs

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of files manipulation, you can use FileUtils from Apache which is really easy to use :
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Look at the methods move*.